# PyFtdi Value Error 'No backend available' every now and then

Tags: python, dll, embedded, ftdi

I'm using pyftdi (https://eblot.github.io/pyftdi/) to handle a FTDI ft4232h. Everything usually works fine but every now and then I come across a ValueError saying 'No backend available'.

Is there any solution regarding that issue? I tried to copy the libusb-1.0.dll to C:\Windows32 as well as to C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
I also tried reinstalling the ftdi driver with zadig as recommended.

Nothing worked so far.

NOTE: I'm bound to windows.

Comment: more likely to get a good answer if you provide a specific example and code rather than "every now and then".  

can you get access to the relevant log files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is this tagged [embedded]?  The code concerned is not embedded.  Where/ when are you seeing this error? Report _all_ diagnostic output _verbatim_.

Comment: Did you follow the advice at https://eblot.github.io/pyftdi/troubleshooting.html#:~:text=%E2%80%9CError%3A%20No%20backend%20available% ?